# Unable to start web server when adding @CssImport

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I'm user Vaadin14 [business starter app](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/starters/business-app/overview) with spring integrated, and I'm trying to add styles, but if I add a css file I get error

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at lu.prefalux.chantier.base.Application.main(Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:200) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

this is the code where I'm adding it

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/charts.css", themeFor = "vaadin-chart", include = "vaadin-chart-default-theme")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/floating-action-button.css", themeFor = "vaadin-button")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/grid.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/border-radius.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/icon-size.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/margin.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/padding.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/shadow.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/spacing.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/typography.css")
// the import below is mine
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/styles.css")
@CssImport("./styles/misc/box-shadow-borders.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/styles.css", include = "lumo-badge")
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge")
@PWA(name = "Chantier", shortName = "Chantier", iconPath = "images/logo-18.png", backgroundColor = "#233348", themeColor = "#233348")
@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes")
public class MainLayout extends FlexBoxLayout
        implements RouterLayout, PageConfigurator, AfterNavigationObserver {
```

I tried naming it with a unique name, and the error still occurs. And when I modify one of the css files already in the project, none of the changes are taken into account.

Comment: Are there any other error messages in the console?

Comment: And what's the file system location of the file that you're trying to add an import for?

Comment: Yes, I had a `Failed to find the following files: ` too, but I didn't saw it at first.

Comment: Might be easier to help if you could edit the original post to also show that error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with IntelliJ (on a multi-module project) and to fix this, I added to the `run/debug configurations` the `working directory` to the module where my frontend file is.